# soa 12c Maven mvn compile issue

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, soa

I had created soa project with below archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate      -DarchetypeGroupId=com.oracle.soa.archetype      -DarchetypeArtifactId=oracle-soa-application      -DarchetypeVersion=12.2.1-3-0    -DgroupId=com.abcd -DartifactId=my-soa-app      -Dversion=1.0      -DprojectName=my-project
```

I also had created empty bpel and tried to compile ...

```
Error ::  The project com.bh.stc:my-project:1.0 (C:\Oracle\Middleware_Devops\Oracle_Home\Devops_Jdev\my-soa-app\my-project\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.oracle.soa:sar-common:12.2.1-3-0: Failure to find com.oracle.maven:oracle-common:pom:12.2.1-3-0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ com.oracle.soa:sar-common:12.2.1-3-0, C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\oracle\soa\sar-common\12.2.1-3-0\sar-common-12.2.1-3-0.pom, line 8, column 11 -> [Help 2]
```

[image]

Comment: This artifact `com.oracle.maven:oracle-common:pom:12.2.1-3-0` does not exist...

Comment: Yes you are right , if figured it and got it fixed ...  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue is oracle-maven-sync:12.2.1-3-0 does not exists and i have updated the same with below command and it working now

mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:12.2.1-3-0:push -DoracleHome=$Oracle_Home overwriteParent=true